# wxpython: adding panel to wx.Frame disables/conflicts with wx.Frame's OnPaint?

Tags: wxpython, panel, frame, draw, onpaint

I just encountered this strange situation: I found an example, where wx.Frame's OnPaint is overridden, and a circle is drawn. Funnily, as soon as I add even a single panel to the frame, the circle is not drawn anymore - in fact, OnPaint is not called *at all* anymore ! (Btw, I tried the example out on Ubuntu Lucid)

Can anyone explain me if this is the expected behavior, and how to correctly handle a wx.Frame's `OnPaint`, if the wx.Frame has child panels ? Small code example is below..

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/wxwidgets-wxpython-drawing-problems-with-onpaint-event-703946/

import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, size=wx.DefaultSize):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title, wx.DefaultPosition, size)

        self.circles = list()
        self.displaceX = 30
        self.displaceY = 30

        circlePos = (self.displaceX, self.displaceY)
        self.circles.append(circlePos)

        ## uncommenting either only first, or both of 
        ## the commands below, causes OnPaint *not* to be called anymore! 
        #~ self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        #~ self.mpanelA = wx.Panel(self.panel, -1, size=(200,50))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, e):
        print "OnPaint called"
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLUE))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.BLUE))

        # Go through the list of circles to draw all of them
        for circle in self.circles:
            dc.DrawCircle(circle[0], circle[1], 10)


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    win = MainWindow(None, "Draw delayed circles", size=(620,460))
    win.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this isn't really trivial, I guess... But I found the thread "[wxPython - drawing without paint event - Python answers](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/690783-wxpython-drawing-without-paint-event)", where it is mentioned:

> One nice strategy from an example in "wxPython in Action" is the
>   following:
>
> - the frame has Draw methods that draw into a BufferedDC, which is
>     chained to a bitmap member,
> - inside the paint method, the bitmap member is drawn to screen

... however, that is actually slightly misleading - if we look at one of those examples, such as [Chapter-06/example1.py](https://github.com/freephys/wxPython-In-Action/blob/357aa1197d7108739be60e95250e76f82aabed24/Chapter-06/example1.py), it is noticeable that the app spawns a `wx.Frame` (as in my example); but the `wx.Frame` here is simply initialized by instantiating a `wx.Window` - and it is **here** where all this DC `onPaint` stuff happens.

With that in mind, my code above can be modified, so it finally works again (i.e. blue circle rendered), as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/wxwidgets-wxpython-drawing-problems-with-onpaint-event-703946/

import wx

class MainWindowWindow(wx.Window):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Window.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.circles = list()
        self.displaceX = 30
        self.displaceY = 30

        circlePos = (self.displaceX, self.displaceY)
        self.circles.append(circlePos)

        ## uncommenting either only first, or both of 
        ## the commands below, now calls onPaint
        ## (without these panels, OnPaint called once - with them, twice)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.mpanelA = wx.Panel(self.panel, -1, size=(200,50))

    def OnPaint(self, e):
        print "OnPaint called"
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLUE))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.BLUE))

        # Go through the list of circles to draw all of them
        for circle in self.circles:
            dc.DrawCircle(circle[0], circle[1], 10)


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, size=wx.DefaultSize):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title, wx.DefaultPosition, size)
        MainWindowWindow(self)


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    win = MainWindow(None, "Draw delayed circles", size=(620,460))
    win.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Well, hope this helps someone,
Cheers!